# trying to attach the where clause to sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, mysql-workbench

HiI am trying  to attach the  where clause to sql statement like this

```
    public static DataTable paymentType(string paymenttype, string ddproviders, string overdue)
    { 

                string paymenttypestr = "";
    string ddproviderstr = "";


    if (paymenttype != "")
    {
        paymenttypestr = string.Format("AND membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod = '{0}'", paymenttype);        

    }
    if (ddproviders != "")
    {
        ddproviderstr = string.Format("AND ddproviders.ddProvider_Name = '{0}'", ddproviders);

    }
    if (overdue == "OverDue-Now")
    { 
       string sql += @"WHERE memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue < NOW() AND memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountDue > memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountPaid ";

    }

    string  sql = string.Format(
                @"SELECT    members.member_Id,
                   members.member_Lastname As Last_name,
                   members.member_Firstname AS First_name,
                   members.member_PostCode  As Post_Code, 
                   ddaccounts.ddAccount_DdReference As dd_reference,
                   ddproviders.ddProvider_Name As dd_providername,
                   memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As monthly_amount,
                   mshiptypes.mshipType_Name As Membership_type,
                   mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name As Status,
                   membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate As Expiry_Date,
                   membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod As payment_method
                   FROM members 
                   LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id
                   LEFT JOIN memberpaysched ON memberpaysched.memberPaySched_memberId = members.member_Id
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN ddaccounts ON ddaccounts.member_Id = members.member_Id
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN  ddproviders ON  ddaccounts.ddProvider_Id=ddproviders.ddProvider_Id 
                   LEFT JOIN   mshipstatustypes ON mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id
                   LEFT JOIN   mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id
                   LEFT JOIN   mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id
                   WHERE       members.member_Active LIKE 'y%'
                   AND               mshipoptions.mshipOption_Period = 'month' 
                   AND               (mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id <> 5)
                   {0}
                   {1}     
                   ORDER BY members.member_Lastname",
                   paymenttypestr, ddproviderstr);
      return getdata(sql,mf);
    }
```

but it was giving error at this line like ";" this symbol is needed;

```
    string sql += @"WHERE memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue < NOW() AND memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountDue > memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountPaid ";
```

I want to add this where clause if overdue == "overdue-now"

how can i add this where clause according to condition

would any one help on this ....

```
Modified Query :   string sql += @"memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue < NOW() AND memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountDue > memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountPaid";
```

still it was showing this  error 
 "Invalid EXPRESSION TERM +="

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN  YOu need to read this to understand why your code is fundamentally flawed and will return incorrect results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no .NET expert, but I'd probably change:

```
if (overdue == "OverDue-Now")     
{
     string sql += @"WHERE memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue < NOW() AND memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountDue > memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountPaid ";      
}
```

to:

```
if (overdue == "OverDue-Now")     
{
     sql += @"AND memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue < NOW() AND   memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountDue > memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountPaid ";      
}
```

(i.e. remove the string keyword, and substitute AND for WHERE)

and put it AFTER the main SQL block (i.e. where you're declaring your string sql variable)..

Answer (score 1):

On 1st glance you have 2 where clauses.  Change the one you're adding to an AND and see what happens.

Comment: it does not working even i change the where to AND it was showing error "INVALID EXPRESSION TERM += "

Comment: The edit you posted above does not show the AND in the front of your addition?

Answer (score 1):

So if overdue == "OverDue-Now" you are declaring a string of sql and +=ing it?  But then you overwrite the string you thought you just created.

I think this is what you're trying to accomplish:

```
if (overdue == "OverDue-Now")     
{
   string isoverduestr = @"AND memberpaysched.memberPaySched_dateDue < NOW() AND memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountDue > memberpaysched.memberPaySched_amountPaid ";      
}
else
{
   string isoverduestr = @"";
}

string  sql = string.Format(
            @"SELECT    members.member_Id,
               members.member_Lastname As Last_name,
               members.member_Firstname AS First_name,
               members.member_PostCode  As Post_Code, 
               ddaccounts.ddAccount_DdReference As dd_reference,
               ddproviders.ddProvider_Name As dd_providername,
               memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As monthly_amount,
               mshiptypes.mshipType_Name As Membership_type,
               mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name As Status,
               membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate As Expiry_Date,
               membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod As payment_method
               FROM members 
               LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id
               LEFT JOIN memberpaysched ON memberpaysched.memberPaySched_memberId = members.member_Id
               LEFT OUTER JOIN ddaccounts ON ddaccounts.member_Id = members.member_Id
               LEFT OUTER JOIN  ddproviders ON  ddaccounts.ddProvider_Id=ddproviders.ddProvider_Id 
               LEFT JOIN   mshipstatustypes ON mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id
               LEFT JOIN   mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id
               LEFT JOIN   mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id
               WHERE       members.member_Active LIKE 'y%'
               AND               mshipoptions.mshipOption_Period = 'month' 
               AND               (mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id <> 5)
               {0}
               {1}
               {2}     
               ORDER BY members.member_Lastname",
               paymenttypestr, ddproviderstr, isoverduestr);
```